# Why second query is invalid about mairadb + spider + mroonga

Tags: web-crawler, mariadb

I install mariadb-10.0.9-spider-3.2-vp-1.1-mroonga-4.0 at ubuntu server

I create table at maria db1 about machine1

```
enter code here

MariaDB [think_db]> CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT  EXISTS text1 (
id int (10) unsigned NOT  NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
title text NOT  NULL ,
text LongText NOT  NULL ,
PRIMARY  KEY  (id),
FULLTEXT INDEX  (text) COMMENT 'parser "TokenUnigram"'
) ENGINE = mroonga DEFAULT  CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.40 sec)

I create table at maria db2 about machine2

```
MariaDB [think_db]> CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT  EXISTS text2 (
id int (10) unsigned NOT  NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
title text NOT  NULL ,
text LongText NOT  NULL ,
PRIMARY  KEY  (id),
FULLTEXT INDEX  (text) COMMENT 'parser "TokenUnigram"'
) ENGINE = mroonga DEFAULT  CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.43 sec)

I create table at spider about machine3

```
MariaDB [think_db]> CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT  EXISTS texts (
id int (10) unsigned NOT  NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
title text NOT  NULL ,
text LongText NOT  NULL ,
PRIMARY  KEY  (id),
FULLTEXT INDEX  (text) COMMENT 'parser "TokenUnigram"'
) ENGINE = SPIDER
PARTITION BY  RANGE (id) (
PARTITION P1 VALUES  LESS THAN (10) COMMENT 'host "XX.XX.XX.XX", port "3306", user "think_user", password "think88", database "think_db", table "text1"' ,
PARTITION p2 VALUES  LESS THAN (20) COMMENT 'host "XX.XX.XX.XX", port "4000", user "think_user", password "think88", database "think_db", table "text2"'
    -> );
```

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

I insert two record..

```
MariaDB [think_db]> insert into texts(title, text) values('Auhui','abcd') ;
```

> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

```
MariaDB [think_db]> insert into texts(title, text) values('Auhui','edfg') ;
```

> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

first query send..==> OK

```
MariaDB [think_db]> SELECT id, title, text FROM texts WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ("abcd" IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 100;
+----+-------+------+
| id | title | text |
+----+-------+------+
|  2 | Auhui | abcd |
+----+-------+------+
```

> 1 row in set (0.01 sec)

i query same query...
second query is invalid...=> why not valid...

```
MariaDB [think_db]> SELECT id, title, text FROM texts WHERE MATCH (text) AGAINST ("abcd" IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 100;
+----+-------+----------------+
| id | title | text           |
+----+-------+----------------+
|  2 | Auhui | abcd           |
|  3 | Auhui | edfg           | <=why return..
+----+-------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove `mariadb-10.0.9-spider-3.2-vp-1.1-mroonga-4.0` and I install `mysql-5.5.34-spider-3.2-vp-1.1-hs-1.2-q4m-0.95` and `groonga-4.0.6 & mroonga-4.06`

And all query success